# Is SQL or NoSQL a better choice for a beginner Django project?

Tags: python, sql, django, nosql

When it comes to actually deploying a Django project, is SQL software, like PostegreSQL, or NoSQL, like MongoDB, a better option?

To evaluate which might be a better choice, you can consider:

- requires less changes to the actual code of the already existing project - for example having to re-do the models structure,
- has correct integration with the backend, i.e.: some years ago MongoDB wouldn't integrate with the Django backend,
- is more beginner friendly.

**Edit**

For this example's sake, let's set some information:

- the project uses models such as `client`, `booking`, `flight`, `hotel`.
- it uses with ForeignKeys.
- it connects a model `client` with django's own `User` model.
- Data needs to be retrieved both to client side and administration side.
- JSON might be used, if necessary, at some point in the future.

Comment: Is this an opinion-based question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, completly! Just looking for a general opinion on wether is more beginner friendly to use SQL or NoSQL in Django projects.

Comment: Typically, decision on what type of database will be used depends more on the nature of the data you will be using in a project, not which language/framework your project is based on. Please provide more detail. (What is it you want to accomplish? Caching? Storing of structured data? JSON storing? etc, etc)

Comment: I'll edit the question with more info @A1isonWondr1and

Comment: If youre simply looking for the easiest/most beginner friendly, id suggest a NoSQL DB. You can cache and store/retrieve simple key/value pairs or documents quickly and easily without worrying about the data structures and relationships.

Comment: @A1isonWondr1and I just added more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SQL DB would be appropriate for this project. This is due to the use of foreign keys, the nature of the models and the relationship between client and user.

You will want to be able to store structured data and be able to maintain relationships between that data, this can be achieved with SQL.